Connecting to Remote database using Android volley
I am new to Android development. I have a database in Hostinger. I am trying to input a record into a table in this database from my android app using Volley. When I try to submit the data, I am getting AuthFailure error. In order to connect to I have create a php file in Hostinger in my account under piblic_html.(public_html/databaseconnect.php). For this I followed the link
https://www.hostinger.in/tutorials/how-to-connect-php-to-mysql.
Attached is my php file(php.jpg). I have hidden the credential here. Also attached is the Android code I am using to send data to DB(Code.png)
When I submit the data, I am getting, com.android.volley.AuthFalureError. I understand its is 403 error. For the URL in StringRequest, I am using the direct link of the php file. ie. open the php file from Hostingerand use the address seen in address bar.
Like https://xxx/xxxxxx/public_html/databaseconnect.php
What is wrong here? If change the method to GET and use google.com as url, I am getting proper response.I understand it has to do with the url of the php file. how to get the correct url?  Please help


I tried by setting the url in a number of ways.No luck.
I expect the data to be uploaded to the hostinger databse

403 means Forbidden. It's not a problem with the URL

Thank you ADyson. How can I resolve this?

Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. I quote from there: "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—copy or type the text into the question." And good luck finding the solution
